# Infinite sum of random numbers

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-distributions

Let $x_n$, with $n=1,2,\ldots$, be uniformly distributed random variables in $(0,1)$

What is the expected value and probability distribution of the sum

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n^{n^n}$$

Comment: Can you provide some motivation for this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elaborating on Steven's answer.

Since $\sum\nolimits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{\rm E}[X_n^{n^n } ]}  < \infty $ and $\sum\nolimits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{\rm Var}[X_n^{n^n } ]}  < \infty $, the series $\sum\nolimits_{n = 1}^\infty  {X_n^{n^n } } $, assuming that the $X_n$ are independent, converges with probability $1$ (see Theorem 1 on page 130 of the book [Probability theory: collection of problems](http://books.google.co.il/books?id=5HKvIDXgdCEC&pg=PA130&lpg=PA130&dq=Probability%20theory%3a%20collection%20of%20problems%20%22series%20of%20independent%20random%20variables%22&source=bl&ots=xGPoDZC5BZ&sig=XYJTGws0o2fkUmuKVn8xEd1H2Wg&hl=iw#v=onepage&q&f=false)). Call the limit $X$. Then, by the monotone convergence theorem, 
$$
{\rm E}[X] = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {\rm E}\bigg[\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {X_k^{k^k } } \bigg] = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {{\rm E}[X_k^{k^k } ]}  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{k^k  + 1}}}  = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n^n  + 1}}} .
$$

EDIT: The fact that the series $\sum\nolimits_{n = 1}^\infty  {X_n^{n^n } } $ converges with probability $1$ follows from the monotone convergence theorem (MCT), and we don't have to assume that the $X_n$ are independent (it suffices that they are positive). Indeed, by MCT, the limit $X:=\sum\nolimits_{n = 1}^\infty  {X_n^{n^n } }$ must be almost surely finite, since the integral $\int_\Omega  {XdP} \,(= \sum\nolimits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n^n  + 1}}})$ is finite.

Comment: Alpha [http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%281%2F%281%2Bn^n%29%29+from+1+to+infinity] shows this as  0.739948.  It gives more digits, but I couldn't copy them.

Comment: @Ross: Thanks for this information.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer almost certainly has no closed form, but it's easy enough to write the EV as a sum; just use the linearity of expectation, and use the defining integral to calculate the expectation of each of the individual terms.